# Why multivariate distribution is used to model weights (polynomial coefficients) for prior distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

Lately, I have been reading Chris Bishop's work on Bayesian linear regression. What was difficult to understand is why is he models $w_0$ and $w_1$ using multivariate Gaussian distribution in prior distribution. See page 155 of Christopher Bishop's book on *Machine learning and pattern recognition*.

Also how do you find the hyperparameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the training sets of the data?

Training set of the data can be supposed as

$D = {(x_1,t_1), (x_2,t_2), \dots , (x_n,t_n)}$

alternatively

$x$ (x-axis) = $(x_1, x_2,...,x_n)$ and $t$ (y-axis or target values) = $(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)$.

Many Thanks